# Inplace plugin and "You cannot upgrade a plugin that is configured via BuildConfig" in Grails 1.3.5

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

My project stopped building from a fresh sandbox. I have an inplace plugin configured in `BuildConfig.groovy`:

`grails.plugin.location.'cxf' = "modified-plugins/cxf-0.5.1"`

It's also in `application.properties`.

When I try to build the project, I get an error:

*Plugin `[cxf]` is aliased as `[grails.plugin.location.cxf]` to the location `[modified-plugins/cxf-0.5.1]` in `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`
You cannot upgrade a plugin that is configured via `BuildConfig.groovy`, remove the configuration to continue.*

If I comment the plugin out of `application.properties`, it doesn't get packaged into `war`.

What can be possibly wrong with my project? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this one. It's an empty plugin.xml generated, a [known issue](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Fatal-Error-1-1-Premature-end-of-file-during-War-build-td2551091.html).